# Round minutes to ceiling using Java 8

Tags: datetime, java-8, rounding, java-time, ceil

So I'm lucky enough to use Java 8 and the new time APi but I don't see any rounding functions...

Basically if the time is...

```
2014-08-28T10:01.00.000 ----> 2014-08-28T10:02.00.000
2014-08-28T10:01.10.123 ----> 2014-08-28T10:02.00.000
2014-08-28T10:01.25.123 ----> 2014-08-28T10:02.00.000
2014-08-28T10:01.49.123 ----> 2014-08-28T10:02.00.000
2014-08-28T10:01.59.999 ----> 2014-08-28T10:02.00.000
```

This seems to be ok, but is it right?

```
LocalDateTime now =  LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
LocalDateTime newTime =  now.plusMinutes(1);

System.out.println(newTime.toString());
System.out.println(newTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:00.000")));
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `10:01` on the right? A ceiling function wouldn't change the value if the fractional part is 0.

Comment: I always want to round up :)

Comment: A round number doesn't change if you round it. What you're asking for is slightly different from a ceiling function.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `java.time` API does not support rounding to ceiling, however it does support [rounding to floor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) (truncation) which enables the desired behaviour (which isn't exactly rounding to ceiling):

```
LocalDateTime now =  LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime roundFloor =  now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
LocalDateTime roundCeiling =  now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).plusMinutes(1);
```

In addition, there is a facility to obtain a clock that only ticks once a minute, which may be of interest:

```
Clock minuteTickingClock = Clock.tickMinutes(ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime now =  LocalDateTime.now(minuteTickingClock);
LocalDateTime roundCeiling =  now.plusMinutes(1);
```

This clock will automatically truncate minutes to floor (although it is [specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#tickMinutes-java.time.ZoneId-) such that it may return a delayed cached value). Note that a `Clock` may be stored in a static variable if desired.

Finally, if this is a common operation that you want to use in multiple places, it is possible to write a library [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) function to perform the rounding. (Adjusters can be written once, tested, and made available as a static variable or method).

Comment: Thanks it's what I need. I know my rounding is a bit weird, but basically I need to query my db system based on the current time. If I have multiple users making a query within the current minute with the rounding up i can cache the filter! :)

Comment: This algorithm would be incorrect for exact-minute times. E.g. let's say the current time is exactly 5 minutes (i.e. 0 seconds, 0 nanos, etc). In that case I would expect roundCeiling to be 5 minutes (i.e. like the ceiling of "1.00" decimal number is "1")  - but the algorithm would give 6 minutes. roundCeiling calculation above should check if the truncated value is the same as 'now' - in that case return 'now', otherwise the +1 minutes.

Comment: Although now I noticed that the original question asks to always round up (even if the number is already round), so the accepted answer is correct in that case.

Answer (score 6):

```
LocalDateTime newTime = now.plusMinutes(1).minusNanos(1).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
```

This will round up to the nearest minute, acting as a ceiling function with minutes as the integer part.

Comment: Where is the simplification? Writing complex `TemporalAdjuster`-implementations should in most cases be limited to frameworks or library writers, not end users. Here the burden to write the adjuster-code is still with the user. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @Meno Hochschild: You're right, I was digging through java.time for relevant functionality and wound up in library writing mode. Definitely overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

`java.time` (the new time API in Java 8) has **no rounding features** like some other libraries. You try to use formatting to round on String-level. If you want to round the time objects however, then you can do this rounding manually:

```
LocalDateTime now =  LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
LocalDateTime newTime =  now.plusMinutes(1).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
```

By the way, you surely meant floor, not ceiling, isn't it?

**Update:**

I have found this slightly better way for setting to floor (obviously the only rounding feature, ceiling is not supported):

```
LocalDateTime now =  LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
LocalDateTime newTime =  now.plusMinutes(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: I mean ceiling, well i want to round up regardless if it's 10 seconds, 25 seconds or 49 seconds.